# sql query to hibernate query in springboot

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a SQL query and I have written it in this way for my java spring code, but it shows error for this query. Google hasn't helped me on this. Can someone answer this please soon

```
@Query("select s from FacilityDetailsEntity s left join RdlftLocFacTypesEntity r on r.rdlftPk:=s.rdlocPk and r.locFacInd:=r.locFacInd and r.deletedRow is null;")
List<FacilityDetailsEntity> getLocFacInd(@Param("locFacInd") String locFacInd,@Param("rdlocPk") Long rdlocPk);
```

Comment: Highlight your code and then press Ctrl-K to make sure it formats correctly.

Comment: We cannot help you if you don't show us the entities. ALso, what's the error?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.bp.rds.repository.FacilityDetailsRepository.getLocFacInd(java.lang.String,java.lang.Long) but parameter 'Optional[locFacInd]' not found in annotated query 'select s from FacilityDetailsEntity s left join RdlftLocFacTypesEntity r on r.rdlftPk:=s.rdlocPk and r.locFacInd:=locFacInd and r.deletedRow is null;'!

Comment: rdloc pk is in fac entity and rlftpk is in rdlftentity. I want to extract rdlft pk from rdlft entity  which has "F" in LocFacInd column in rdlft

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'facilityDetailsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.bp.rds.repository.FacilityDetailsRepository.getLocFacInd(java.lang.String,java.lang.Long) but parameter 'Optional[locFacInd]' not found in annotated query 'select s from FacilityDetailsEntity s left join RdlftLocFacTypesEntity r on r.rdlftPk:=s.rdlocPk and r.locFacInd:=locFacInd and r.deletedRow is null;'!